# InDesign CS5 / Extendscript -- What are the parameters for exportFile, and what are its' related properties?

Tags: javascript, export, adobe-indesign, extendscript

There is very poor documentation on Extendscript for InDesign online, and I otherwise cannot find any detailed / useful information on the `exportFile` method... this is all I could find, which is fairly well garbled:   http://jongware.mit.edu/idcs5/pe_ExportFormat.html.

---

A common such statement I have seen using `exportFile` would be:

       `imgs[i].exportFile(ExportFormat.JPG, img, false)`.

This statement uses the `JPG` property of `ExportFormat`, is passing a file object `img`, and is passing the parameter `false`.

I know that the file object has to be instantiated in such a way:

       `var img = new File(folder + "/" + fileName)`.

...but WTF is `false` for?

Also, it seems as if different file-type properties for the `ExportFormat` object are instantiated in different ways... For instance, I have seen a PDF's ExportFormat to be instantiated as `ExportFormat.pdfType`. This variation throws me off, and other file-types seem to have unique property names as well.

---

So, what exactly are the parameters for the `exportFile` method, and what are all of the properties of these parameters?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think resources are quite numerous if you where to find them ;)
I really advise you having this bookmark as a favourite :
http://jongware.mit.edu/idcs5js_html_3.0.3i/idcs5js/

Once that done, navigate to the pageItem ( Layout ) link and see for exportFile method :

void exportFile (format: varies, to: File[, showingOptions: bool=false][, using: PDFExportPreset][, versionComments: string][, forceSave: bool=false])
Exports the object(s) to a file.

the false means you do not want to use a PDF Export Preset.

Loic

Comment: Thanks @Loic for pointing me to this link. I am aware of the jongware documentation on the InDesign object model, and at times it can be very useful. Unfortunately, the page on `exportFile` is difficult to understand, as the method itself is not very self-explanatory and there is no clarification beyond its' programmatical definition...

Comment: ...and thanks for clarifying that "false means you do not want to use a PDF Export Preset".

Answer (score 3):

//PDF export preset)

```
//The default PDF export preset names are surrounded by square breackets

//(e.g., "[High Quality Print], [Press Quality], or [Smallest File Size]").
var myPDFExportPreset = app.pdfExportPresets.item("[Press Quality]");

myDocument.exportFile(
    ExportFormat.pdfType,
    File(Folder.desktop + "/ExportPDFWithPreset.pdf"),
    false, 
    myPDFExportPreset
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, no doubt [jongware](http://jongware.mit.edu/idcs5js_html_3.0.3i/idcs5js/) has done a lot for the InDesign scripting community, as well as http://indesignsecrets.com/...

I do think that Adobe should provide more thorough documentation themselves though, if they want to reach a wider audience ([click here to see the Adobe documentation](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/indesign/documentation.html)).

---

I think this guy Andy Matthews put it well when he said:

> "It's worth noting that the documentation for ExtendScript isn't the
>   greatest. If you're used to the docs for Actionscript or ColdFusion,
>   then not only will you be disappointed, but you're going to be
>   confused as well... 
>  ...I do wish that Adobe would put a
>   litle more effort into making their tooling and documentation top
>   notch. It would definitely make a difference, and would greatly reduce
>   frustration and could encourage more designers/developers to talk
>   about this software." 
>  ([click here to see this page](http://www.andymatthews.net/read/2011/11/25/Scripting-Photoshop-with-JavaScript-and-ExtendScript))

---

As far as books go:

In seeking good resources on Extendscript in InDesign, I have found that the book [Scripting InDesign CS3/4 with JavaScript](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596802530.do) was a really good introduction to Extendscript in InDesign, but it gives only very basic examples...

However, soon I will have the book [InDesign CS5 Automation Using XML & JavaScript](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1460915380) by Grant Gamble, which seems like a much more comprehensive guide. This book apparently includes the entirety of his other book [InDesign CS5 JavaScript](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1463667442)  **plus** the information about XML.

Comment: Yep these are great resources too. Given the lack or no lack of documentation, I have often understood logic and then realized I had it at hand. Most of what we need are in the scripting guides and the Javascript Tool Guide provided by Adobe.
A cleared documentation? possibly yes. Do we lack documentation, don't think so :D

Comment: Ok, thanks @Loic. I'll give http://jongware.mit.edu/idcs5js_html_3.0.3i/idcs5js/ more attention, and see what else I may be able to find in the Adobe documentation...

Comment: **UPDATE** -- I have found more thorough information at this point, thanks to Loic's urging, see here -- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9222442/rapidly-learn-indesign-scripting/11767298#11767298.